# Cómo refrescar la UI y luego seguir con las tareas "Pesadas" C#

Tags: wpf

Cómo hacer para que aparezca la primer "leyenda1" luego se ejecute todoelcodigo() y por último se vea la "leyenda2".
Ya que una vez que se presiona el botón, no se ve el primer texto.

```
private void botEnviar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string leyenda1 = "Enviando archivo comprimido...";
    string leyenda2 = "El archivo fue enviado con éxito!";

    try
    {
        lbLeyenda.DataContext = leyenda1; 
        //Acá quiero mostrar el texto y 
        //que luego siga con las otras tareas...

         todoelcodigo(); //Se queda haciendo esto...

         lbLeyenda.DataContext = leyenda2;
         //Lo único que se ve es el texto de la leyenda2
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ControlDatos.mensajeError(ex);
        deleteAllDirectoryes();

    }

    private void todoelcodigo()
    {
        copyFilesToTempDirectory();
        compressFile();
        uploadFile(@"C:\windows\Temp\tmpExport\ZIP\", "SIS" + mes + año + 
         ".zip");
        deleteAllDirectoryes();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque estás trabajando en el mismo hilo de la UI, para que tu código trabaje en un hilo diferente a la UI y esta no se te 'congele' al ejecutar una tarea debes usar programación asíncrona, y eso además te permitirá asignar valores a los controles y que se reflejen cuando corresponda y esas instrucciones no se solapen.

Podrías probar algo así:

```
string leyenda1 = "Enviando archivo comprimido...";
string leyenda2 = "El archivo fue enviado con éxito!";

private void CallEnviar()
{
    var tsk = EnviarAsync();
}

async Task EnviarAsync()
{
    try
    {
        lbLeyenda.Content = leyenda1;
        await Task.Run(() => todoelcodigo());
        lbLeyenda.Content = leyenda2;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ControlDatos.mensajeError(ex);
        deleteAllDirectoryes();
    }
}

private void todoelcodigo()
{
    copyFilesToTempDirectory();
    compressFile();
    uploadFile(@"C:\windows\Temp\tmpExport\ZIP\", "SIS" + mes + año +
    ".zip");
    deleteAllDirectoryes();
}
```

Si te fijas el "await" hace que el proceso "espere" y luego hace lo que viene en la linea que continúa, eso permitirá que tu Label muestre los valores que le asignas antes y después de la ejecución de "todoelcodigo()" sin necesidad de que tú refresques la UI.

Espero te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: Perfecto Ledev! Funciona lo mas bien. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: De nada, solo una cosa más, trabajar desde otro hilo te impedirá setear valores a controles de la UI, así que debes acceder a ellos a través del Dispacher.